# GlassFish server not start in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

i have tired setup glassfish server in eclipse , i have do not understand what is my fault?
1. jdk1.7.0_71
2.glassfish 4.1
3.Eclipse Luna
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27oll.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with glassfish in eclipse, I ended up using NetBeans (download [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)) just for glassfish and eclipse for coding. Netbeans has glassfish preinstalled, so its easy to start it up.

Services -> Servers -> Glassfish (right click and start)

Wait for couple of minutes to start it up.
The go to your browser: http://localhost:4848 - this is admin panel for glassfish, you can find a lot of stuff in there (deploy app etc.)

e.g: go to Application, you can deploy apps from there. You can find some tutorials online.

In eclipse, create your app, export as a WAR file and then deploy in Glassfish.

Comment: give me details , i am new user

Comment: I updated my answer @brids. You can find some tutorial online how to use glassfish and how to export apps from eclipse in a right format.